# Convert XML document attributes into new XML document with only those attributes

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm having some problem, I need to convert XML document attributes into new XML document with only those attributes.

I tried different things and I came up with

```
Console.WriteLine(attrVal)
```

and I have those attributes into console but I need to write them into XML.

So my code is:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace MResourceWriter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(@"myfile.resx");

        XmlNodeList elemList = xml.GetElementsByTagName("data");
        for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
        {
            string attrVal = elemList[i].Attributes["name"].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(attrVal);
        }

       }
    }
}
```

I have this input - so attributes into console [image]

and I want convert those values in brand new XML document.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. At the moment I'm afraid your question is unclear - you've presented some code, but you haven't told us in what way it doesn't work. It would really help if you'd present an example of the input document and the expected output document. As an aside, I'd also strongly recommend using the LINQ to XML API instead of the old XmlDocument API - LINQ to XML is much easier to read. I'd also recommend constructing the output document in memory rather than using XmlTextWriter - again, it'll lead to simpler code.

Comment: Thank you very much Jon. Code writes all attributes into Console through this line Console.WriteLine(attrVal); , and I want to get rid of that line and move those results into a separate XML document with only those results.

Comment: Okay, so presumably you'd just need to make a call to `writer` instead of calling `Console.WrirteLine`. Have you looked at what methods are available on `writer`? (As I said, I wouldn't do it this way anyway, but...)

Comment: Could you show us what you have and what result you need?

Comment: Down here, Gauravsa also recommend Linq to XML method for more info, so I would like to go that way. Also thanks you very much for the recommendation.

Comment: JohnyL, look up, I added a picture and explained.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Linq to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview):

```
XElement dataValues = XElement.Load($"{fileName}");

IEnumerable<XElement> names =  from item in dataValues.Descendants("data")  
                                 select item.Element("name");
```

You can then create XML tree. The code can look like below:

```
XElement xmlfromlist = new XElement("Root",
                                 from a in dataValues.Descendants("data")  
                                 select
                                   new XElement("Name", a.Element("name"));
```

Comment: And now, I have a brand new file named SomeFile.xml, and I want to put that values in that file. I'll research Linq to XML, thanks for the answer.